# Writing SoX Stats to File When Running via .bat

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, stderr, sox

Amateur coder here. I have an old R script that runs SoX stats on files across multiple folders and writes the outputs to txt files. A peer requested to use it on their Windows machine and would like to be able to just click a .bat file to run it. I made one but it outputs SoX stats to the batch file window and the txt files the stats typically output to are blank. I've read it's because of how R handles stderr but I can't find a solution for my issue. I'm really only versed in R but have been teaching myself Python, so if there's an alternative language solution like that, I'm all ears.

**My "sox-stats.R" Script**

```
setwd("~/R/sox-stats/")

for(l in list.dirs(recursive=FALSE)){
  setwd(paste0("~/R/sox-stats/", l))
  print(paste0("Directory set to ", l))
  dir.create("./stats/", showWarnings = FALSE)
  directoryAll <- list.files()
  statFolder <- list.files(pattern="stats")

  for(file in setdiff(directoryAll, statFolder)){
    firstSox <- paste("sox \"",file,"\" -n stats",sep="")
    write(system(firstSox, intern = TRUE), paste("./stats/", file, "_stats.txt", sep=""))
    print(paste0(file, " has been processed."))    
  }
}
```

**My .bat File**

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Hello, so you want to get some SoX Stats?
ECHO ------------------------------------------------   
ECHO            Press any key to start me up!
PAUSE >NUL
cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\bin
rscript sox-stats.R
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO SoX Says: Something went wrong. Check messages 
above for clues. Press any key to close SoX Stats.
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO SoX Says: PROCESSING COMPLETE. Press any key to close this window 
and open your "sox-stats" folder.
pause >nul   
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "C:\Users\user\Documents\R\sox-stats"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to use Julia, which is [available for Windows](http://julialang.org/downloads/). The meat of the process would be something like:

```
run(pipeline(`soxi mytest.wav`,"soxi.out"))
```

This code uses backticks to signal a console command to Julia, sets up a pipe into a named file and runs the whole thing. You could examine the contents of directories as required with a `readdir()` into an array of filenames and place a filter on the array as required.